# Wordpress Custom Taxonomy - get_the_terms_list();

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I've got a custom taxonomy called "Artists". I'd like to be able to display the artists as follows:

```
[Main Artist / First in Array] ft. [Second Artists], [Third Artist] & [Last Artist]
```

The code I'm currently using to display the "Artist" is:

```
<?php $artists_links = get_the_term_list( $track->ID, 'artists', '', ' ', '' );
      $artists_withoutlinks = strip_tags( $artists_links );
      echo $artists_withoutlinks ?>
```

So would anyone be able to help with this? In summary all I want to be able to do is:

- Change the separator after the first term to "ft."
- Change the separator before the last term to "&"

Obviously I want to keep database calls to a minimum, and make the query as fast as possible, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `get_the_terms()` instead of `get_the_term_list()`. While the latter fetches the terms into a string, the first creates an array of terms. Still only one query. Create the string from the array afterwards:

```
<?php
    $artists = get_the_terms( $track->ID, 'artists' );
    $artist_string = '';
    $length = count($artists);
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $artist_string .= strip_tags( $artists[$i] );
        if ( $i == 0 )
            $artist_string .= ' ft. ';
        elseif ( $i == $length - 2 )
            $artist_string .= ' & ';
        elseif ( $i != $length - 1 )
            $artist_string .= ', ';
    }
    echo $artist_string;
?>
```

Comment: Another problem I'm having is the order of the tags. I can't seem to find anything that will let me display the tags in the order that I attach them to the track.

Any suggestions